# My CORS with .Net 6 and Angular application work in local but dont work in IIS

Tags: .net, angular, iis, cors, .net-6.0

I spent 2 days to try to get CORS working with my Angular in Front and .Net 6 Core in back, and I cry...

I created a simple angular application. Juste a "get" that hit my backend API.
In my backend API, I created a simple project, and  I did this in my program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var policyName = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
        builder =>
        {
            builder
            .WithMethods("POST")
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            //.AllowAnyOrigin()
        });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseCors(policyName);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and in my simple controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors("_myAllowSpecificOrigins")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

When I test in localhost, I have access to my get result:

[image]

Even though I didnt put GET in withMethods.

If I put
`.WithOrigins("http://hhhhhh:4200");`

I get
[image]

When I put Angular and .Net Core application in IIS, it always work, while I put
 `.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");`
I tried a lot of things,  but the site is always working, I never got the message 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource...'
How I have to setup IIS ?

Please Help!!
Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: IIS has its CORS module, and you should use that.

Comment: There are three ways to fix from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy error in Angular applications.

1. Change the back end API to accept requests from http://localhost:4200.
2. Using alias domain
3. Proxying to a backend server.

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

If you try to access cross domain back end API from the Angular application, you might get from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy error. This error is caused by the Same-Origin Policy and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) mechanisms in the browser.

In your error message, you are trying to access the resource http://localhost:5112/WeatherForecast from a source at http://localhost:4200. But the server does not set the appropriate CORS header to allow this cross-origin request, so the browser blocks the request.

To solve this problem, you need to include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response, which specifies the domain from which access to the resource is allowed:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
```

The Microsoft IIS CORS Module is an extension that enables web sites to support the CORS(Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) protocol. If you want to know how to use the CORS module in IIS, please refer to: [IIS CORS module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference)

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your policy,

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
        builder =>
        {
            builder
            .WithMethods("POST")
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            //.AllowAnyOrigin()
        });
});
```

It seems you only have allowed POST requests. And You try to call GET request.
For that, you need to make some changes in Policy as below:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: policyName,
        builder =>
        {
            builder
            .WithMethods("POST", "GET")  // Allow both POST and GET
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
            //.AllowAnyOrigin()
        });
});
```